# How to set up K&R everywhere (1TBS) brace style in cc-mode?

Tags: indentation, customize, c++, cc-mode, java

I'd like Emacs to follow this indentation style:

```
struct Foo {
    void bar() {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if (condition) {
                // code
                // code
            }
        }
    }
    auto lambda = []() {
        // code
    };
};
```

Pretty much K&R brace style everywhere (One true brace style) followed by a uniform indent.

Comment: `(setq c-default-style "k&r")` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932388/kr-c-indentation-in-emacs

Comment: @TianshuWang this is not what I'm looking for since it forces Allman's style on structs and functions.

Comment: Use the menu-bar and look for ```guess-style``` of your snippet code and follow with ```set-style``` and write it to your init file.

Comment: @Ian guess-style returned the default K&R style which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation I've implemented this style as such:

```
(c-add-style "1tbs"
         '("java"
           (c-hanging-braces-alist
             (defun-open after)
             (class-open after)
             (inline-open after)
             (block-close . c-snug-do-while)
             (statement-cont)
             (substatement-open after)
             (brace-list-open)
             (brace-entry-open)
             (extern-lang-open after)
             (namespace-open after)
             (module-open after)
             (composition-open after)
             (inexpr-class-open after)
             (inexpr-class-close before)
             (arglist-cont-nonempty))
           (c-offsets-alist
             (access-label . -))))
```

Paste this into your `.emacs` file. You can now enable this style by setting the `c-default-style` variable to `"1tbs"`.